# CSS - Ensuring the first two rows of my CSS grid is equal to the remaining height of the screen (excluding header)

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am wondering if the first two rows of my CSS grid can be equal to the height of the screen excluding the header. The content container below the header has been set to overflow: auto, but I would want only my first two rows of the grid to be equal to the height of the content container (without overflowing). My grid has a total of 3 rows, and basically, I want the first two rows to take up the entire height of the container without overflowing, followed by the third row being completely invisible to the screen unless the container is scrolled down. Do let me know if my explanation is confusing, as I am new to CSS grid, and not too sure if my explanation has been sufficient. Thanks all, and I look forward to your replies!

Here's a sample of my HTML layout

```
<div class='entire'>
    <div class='header'>Header</div>
    <div class='content'>
        <div class='grid'>
            item 1
            item 2
            item 3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.entire {
  height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  overflow: auto;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: ___ ____ ____;
}
```

Comment: I don't believe this is possible unless the height of the header is known.

Comment: if i get the height of the header, i would have to use calc() to get the remaining height? how do i incorporate that into the grid by specifying that i want that calculated height to span 2 rows?

Comment: If you know the height of the header then you can calculate the height of the content div and then your grid rows will be 50% of that. No?

Comment: oh sorry i forgot to mention, i would want the first row height to be auto, and the second row height to take up the remaining height of that container, is there a simple way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The height of `.header` should be defined in CSS. If not - it should be get by JS. Let's agree with definition in CSS.
2. Taking into account your last comment about 1st and 2nd row which should be both fit into one screen, 1st should take auto height and 2nd - all the rest height, I don't see any evidence to include the block 3rd into the `grid` at all. Moved it away.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.entire {
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  background: cyan;
  height: 20px;
}

.content {
  overflow: auto;
}

.grid {
  /* subtracting known height of .header */
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  /* this will make 1st row auto height and 2nd - all the rest */
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr; 
}

.item1 {
  background: #eee;
}

.item2 {
  background: #ddd;
}

.item3 {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="entire">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="item1">item 1</div>
      <div class="item2">item 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item3">item 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: oh thank you! i did not think of leaving the third item out of the grid, works wonderful, thanks!